# Does an activity has inflate method?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-inflate

I found at the internet the following code:

```
   package com.example.myapplication

import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.graphics.Typeface
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Layout
import android.text.StaticLayout
import android.text.TextPaint
import android.util.Log
import com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import kotlin.math.max

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            var maxValue = 0f
            val longestText = "W 140-108"

            val painter = TextPaint()
            painter.isAntiAlias = true
            painter.textSize = 15 * resources.displayMetrics.density
            binding.result.layoutParams.width = painter.measureText(longestText).toInt()
            binding.result.text = longestText
        }
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

I tried to understand the code but couldn't understand what dose the following code (also i didn't find the method **inflate** inside the **Activity** api

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

Comment: Read this page. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Comment: @Tenfour04, Thanks. I've read. Can you please explain me two things:
1. what  is the difference between **binding** and **binding.root** (aren't they both the same **View**?
2.Why i can't find **inflate** method inside Activity api?

Comment: Binding isn’t a view. It’s a class with a bunch of references to views. Activity doesn’t have an inflate method. The code above calls inflate on the binding factory function.

Comment: @Tenfour04, i understand. Thanks. Sorry for bothering you, but i will be more than glad to understand how **resource.displayMetrics.density** works if we didn't declare any *resource* reference

Comment: `resources` is a property of Context/Activity. You can control-click properties in the IDE and it will jump to where it is declared.